# How to extract group match to array?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string such as:

```
<?xml version="xyzt" standalone="112.0" sxcx="xcxc"?>
```

I want to extract the string to array where each element is an attribute of string such as `[version="xyzt", standalone="112.0", sxcx="xcxc"]`.

I tried using `string.scan(/\s\w+="\.*"/) do |block| puts block end` but I don't get a result.. Please tell me why and how I can do it.

Comment: Well, that regex doesn't match anything in that string. Therefore, no output.

Comment: I am preeeetty sure you don't want to match literal dot zero or more times. Use http://regex101.com, it's great.

Comment: Please consider using an actual XML parser (e.g. [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/)) instead of [parsing XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/).

Comment: Additionally, your example output array is not valid Ruby.

Comment: Thank @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMarshall but i don't want use module

Comment: Further to @Andrew's point about the output array being invalid, the first element of the array you've shown (`version="xyzt"`) implies that `version` is a local variable produced from the given string. Since Ruby v1.8 it has not been possible to create local variables. The question only makes sense if the first element of the array is the string `'version="xyzt"'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[/(?<=\<\?xml ).*(?=\?>)/]
#⇒ 'version="xyzt" standalone="112.0" sxcx="xcxc"'
```

If you need to surround it with square brackets:

```
?[ << string[/(?<=\<\?xml ).*(?=\?>)/] << ?]
#⇒ '[version="xyzt" standalone="112.0" sxcx="xcxc"]'
```

To get a hash of attributes:

```
string[/(?<=\<\?xml ).*(?=\?>)/].split(/\s+/)
                                .map { |e| e.split('=') }
                                .to_h
#⇒ {
#  "standalone" => "\"112.0\"",
#        "sxcx" => "\"xcxc\"",
#     "version" => "\"xyzt\""
# }
```

Comment: He wants array of attributes.

Comment: Oh my been a long time since I’ve seen the `?` character string literal used.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It saves one keypress per char constant :)

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '<?xml version="xyzt" standalone="112.0" sxcx="xcxc"?>'
```

I assume you want to produce the array:

```
['version="xyzt"', 'standalone="112.0"', 'sxcx="xcxc"']
```

You can do that as follows:

```
arr = str.scan(/[a-z]+\=\S+/)
  #=> ["version=\"xyzt\"", "standalone=\"112.0\"", "sxcx=\"xcxc\"?>"] 

puts arr
# version="xyzt"
# standalone="112.0"
# sxcx="xcxc"?>
```